# PostgreSQL: Select statement without header / footer lines

Tags: postgresql, psql

```
select distinct table_schema from information_schema.tables;
```

provides something like

```
   table_schema    
--------------------
 mySchema
 pg_catalog
 information_schema
 anotherSchem
(4 rows)
```

How to modify the command, in order not to see the first two (table_schema and ---) nor the last line (... rows)?

I'm using a psql command in a bash script. how can I add `\pset tuples ...` there?

Comment: That's client dependent. What client do you use?

Comment: In `psql` you can use `\pset tuples_only`

Comment: I'm using a psql comman in a bash script. how can I add the \pset tuples ... there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a shell script, you can use the `psql` option `--tuples-only` (shorter `-t`), which is more convenient than using `\pset`:

```sh
psql -t -c 'SELECT ...'
```

If you are only interested in a single query result, it is often best to do away with alignment and status messages as well:

```sh
result="$(psql -Atq -c 'SELECT ...')"
```

Comment: Thank you, the -Atq solves it. I guess, that's the easiest.

Answer (score 4):

In `psql` you can use the [meta command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) `\pset tuples_only` to turn this off:

```
postgres=> select distinct table_schema from information_schema.tables;
    table_schema
--------------------
 public
 pg_catalog
 information_schema
(3 rows)

postgres=>postgres=> \pset tuples_only
Tuples only is on.

postgres=> select distinct table_schema from information_schema.tables;
 public
 pg_catalog
 information_schema
```

You can turn this on when starting `psql` by using the command line parameter `--tuples-only`:

```
psql --tuples-only -U micha -d some_db
```